# HTML5 File API and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I'm using a script that takes advantage of the HTML5 files API and uses AJAX to send the file to a php upload file. The problem I am having is that it was written (I think..) to handle multiple uploads, as there are several iteration loops to process all files.

Maybe this is too simple of a question but is there a way to make this single file only? What is happening is that I will choose a file in the browser to send, then click the upload button, and it uploads without refreshing the page. If I remain on the page and upload a second file, it actually uploads the same file twice in a row. This will continue forever.

This is how the files are prepared:

```
var files;

    // Grab the files and set them to our variable
    function prepareUpload(event)
    {
        files = event.target.files;

    }
```

I thnk I read to add files[0] to the end but that breaks the upload function (it calls success but nothing is actually uploaded).

As for the iteration loops which are the evidence that this is supposed to be a multifile uploader:

```
function uploadFiles(event)
    {var data = new FormData();
                $.each(files, function(key, value)
                {
                    data.append(key, value);
                });



function submitForm(event, data)
    {$.each(data.files, function(key, value)
                {
                    formData = formData + '&filenames[]=' + value;
                    console.log(value);
                });
```

What I am confused on is what kind of variable is files? Is it an array of objects? I cannot find this info in my searches.

PHP:

```
if (isset($_FILES)) {
if(isset($_GET['files']))
{   
    $error = false;
    $files = array();
    $uploaddir = '../uploads/';


        foreach($_FILES as $file)
        {   
            if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir .basename($file['name'])))
            {
                $files[] = $uploaddir .$file['name'];                   
            }else{
                $error = true;
            }
        }
    $data = ($error) ? array('error' => 'There was an error uploading your files') : array('files' => $files);
}else{
    $data = array('success' => 'Form was submitted', 'formData' => $_POST);     
}}echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's techically a `fileList`, an array-like object.

From the docs :

> An object of this type is returned by the files property of the HTML
>   input element; this lets you access the list of files selected with
>   the  element. It's also used for a list of files
>   dropped into web content when using the drag and drop API; see the
>   DataTransfer object for details on this usage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

To clear the input after the upload, clone it and replace it to keep the event handler but loose the value

```
function submitForm(event, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function(key, value) {
         formData = formData + '&filenames[]=' + value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        // upload stuff
    }).done(function() {
        var clone = $(event.target).clone(true);
        $(event.target).replaceWith(clone);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hm, that did not seem to work. Perhaps my issue is in the PHP upload file...$files = array();... foreach($_FILES as $file) { $files[] = $uploaddir .$file['name'];}

Comment: Do you have an input with the name "files" ?

Comment: Yeah it's kinda strange to me. There are two functions, uploadFiles and submitForm. Both have a pretty similar AJAX POST. The first one is posting to the upload.php?files, and its sending FormData, but processData is false. The second AJAX POST sends a serialized formData appended with filenaem to upload.php.